# How to delete multi column unique index on destroying a record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am working on a [spreecommerce](http://spreecommerce.com/) 3.0.2 app on Rails 4.2

Spree defines an index on spree_shipping_rates table (taken from my schema.rb file):

```
add_index "spree_shipping_rates", ["shipment_id", "shipping_method_id"], name:     "spree_shipping_rates_join_index", unique: true, using: :btree
```

However, when a spree_shipping_rates record is destroyed, it appears that the index entry still persists as I get the following error when creating **the same record again**:

```
PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "spree_shipping_rates_join_index"
DETAIL:  Key (shipment_id, shipping_method_id)=(3, 3) already exists.
```

My questions is how can I make sure that the associated unique index is removed when a spree_shipping_rates record is destroyed?

**Some context:**

In spree, when a user is checking out and enters shipping and billing address and saves, a new shipment for the order is created and any existing shipments are destroyed.

[checkout.rb line 95:](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/core/app/models/spree/order/checkout.rb)

```
if states[:delivery]
    before_transition to: :delivery, do: :create_proposed_shipments
    .
    .
end
```

[order.rb line 474:](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/core/app/models/spree/order.rb)

```
def create_proposed_shipments
  adjustments.shipping.delete_all
  shipments.destroy_all
  self.shipments = Spree::Stock::Coordinator.new(self).shipments
end
```

[shipment.rb line 22:](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/3-0-stable/core/app/models/spree/shipment.rb)

```
has_many :shipping_rates, -> { order('cost ASC') }, dependent: :delete_all
```

As you can see, all associated shipping rates get "deleted" when order's shipments are destroyed.

Does `:delete_all` in the above code block not remove the indexes? Should this be `:destroy`?

Comment: should be `:dependent: :destroy`, `destroy_all` is invalid

Comment: Thanks. I made the correction in my last question. But does `:delete_all` not remove the associated indexes?

Comment: What you describe - a row being removed but indexes on that table isn't possible (or at least would be a serious bug in Postgres). You'll have to dig deeper to find out why the rows you expect to be remove aren't.